# Auto Layout - How to add a subview to match the size of a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am stuck on a issue I have encountering with Auto Layout. 
 I have a `UIView` that has constraints set so it is in the same position for every size class. I am trying to get my video to fit perfectly inside of this `UIView` `videoViewBox`. I got it working on iPhone 6 only, but if I switch to iPhone 4S/5, the video is no longer aligned.

This is the code:

```
    var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerController!

    @IBOutlet var videoViewBox: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("tutorial", ofType: "mov")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 255, height: 400)
        videoViewBox.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)

        moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
    }
```

I tried setting the values of `CGRect` dynamically with the values from `videoViewBox.frame.origin.x` and `videoViewBox.frame.origin.y`, but it wasn't aligned either.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't set the frame for the moviePlayer view.  Instead, add Autolayout constraints to constrain the moviePlayer view to its superview.  You can do this using the Visual Format:

```
moviePlayer.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
videoViewBox.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)

let views = ["moviePlayerView": moviePlayer.view]

let hconstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[moviePlayerView]|", metrics: nil, views: views)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(hconstraints)

let vconstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[moviePlayerView]|", metrics: nil, views: views)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(vconstraints)
```

---

Alternatively, you can use anchors:

```
moviePlayer.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
videoViewBox.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)

moviePlayer.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoViewBox.topAnchor).isActive = true
moviePlayer.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoViewBox.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
moviePlayer.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoViewBox.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
moviePlayer.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoViewBox.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thank you very much, simpler than I thought!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AutoLayoutConstrains to achieve this.

You can both, apply such constrains directly over your storyboard or by code. I'm assuming that what you want is to do it by code. In that case this should be the way to go:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("tutorial", ofType: "mov")
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
let movieView = moviePlayer.view!

//this will be the height of your control
var heightValue: CGFloat = 400

//This will leave a marging of 50 on top
var top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: movieView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: videoViewBox, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 50 )
//This will be the height of the control
var height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: movieView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: heightValue )
//This will leave a marging of 10 at the end
var trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: movieView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: videoViewBox, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
//This will leave a marging of 10 at the start
var leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: movieView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: videoViewBox, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)

movieView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([top, height, trailing, leading])
    videoViewBox.addSubview(movieView)

moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
```